# Type of PayPal button

Tags: php, button, paypal

Im developing web application with credit system. It means that users can change money for credits. I just want to ask someone more experienced, what type of PayPal button is the best solution for this kind of application.

Thank for any hints.

Comment: what programming language?..

Comment: oh sorry, application is in PHP.

Comment: You probably want to use IPN for this. Google Paypal IPN and you will find the mechanism that sends requests to your server after money is received. Then you can create a custom PHP form and get a request to the server if the money is received.

Comment: Yes, IPN i`ll use, but i have to choose one of 5 buttons, which paypal offers (shopping cart, buy now, donations, gift certificates or subscriptions) and that`s my problem. I think, the best button for my app is donation, but i`m not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular *"Buy Now"* button. You are selling a sort of prepaid service.

Comment: But i want to change money for credits.  And users will buy any services for this credits. There is a posibility to use buy now button. But i should use input "amount" as type text instead hidden. Is it correct solution?